# Linq to foreach without intermediate select (Cartesian Product)

Tags: c#, linq

Given

```
var query = 
  from dog in Dogs
  from puppy in Puppies
  select new
  {
    Dog = dog,
    Puppy = puppy
  };
  foreach (var pair in q)
  {
    adopt(pair.Dog, pair.Puppy);
  }
```

Is there a way to cut out the intermediate select, and immediately invoke the action adopt?

**Edit**: The result I'm looking for is definitely a Cartesian product, just the names are probably slightly off as I couldn't think of a good naming scheme.

```
Dogs = [1,2,3], Puppies = [a,b,c]
call adopt 9 times, in any order, for all combinations
e.g. 1,a 1,b 1,c 2,a 2,b 2,c 3,a 3,b 3,c
```

**Edit2**:

I falsely claimed that it was possibly in Java in the comments without libraries, this is the closest I could get.

```
    IntStream dogs = IntStream.range(1, 4);
    IntStream puppies = IntStream.range(1, 4);
    dogs.forEach(
            d -> puppies.forEach(p ->
                adopt(d, p)
            )
    );
}

public static void adopt(int dog, int puppy){

}
```

Comment: No, once you have a join, you need to select out the elements of the join. I realize this is just sample code, but it doesn't appear to be correct. As it stands, every dog will adopt every puppy. Your query is doing a cartesian join. Perhaps what you're looking for is Zip()?

Comment: Why is this an issue? What are you hoping to achieve? Just a little less code?

Comment: @Enigmativity I'm new to C#, coming from Java where it is possible. maybe codereview.stackexchange would have been more appropriate.

Comment: @Rob my analogy is probably a little off, I was definitely after a Cartesian product.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach - How is this possible in Java? Could you show that? Java doesn't have LINQ (or an equivalent as far as I know). Maybe there's an equivalent approach in C#?

Comment: @Enigmativity java has streams which is _kind of_ similar to LINQ but yeah id be curious to see how it's done in Java ;-)

Comment: @RyanTheLeach Fair enough. In that case, what you've got is pretty much as good as you're going to get. The only thing you can shorten here is to replace the select statement with `select new { dog, puppy };` instead of `select new { Dog = dog, Puppy = puppy };`. You can then change `from dog` to `from Dog` if you need to keep the same naming conventions

Comment: @Aominè - What do "streams" look like in Java to perform what the OP is trying to do?

Comment: Using Microsoft's Interactive Framework (NuGet "System.Interactive") you can do this: `Dogs.SelectMany(d => Puppies, (Dog, Puppy) => new { Dog, Puppy }).ForEach(pair => Adopt(pair.Dog, pair.Puppy));`. Is that the kind of thing you're after?

Comment: @Aominè it's not as elegant as I'd like in Java, was getting some of my streams crossed with Scala. but writing it out in Java and realizing my error is starting to lead me to the answer in C#

Comment: @Enigmativity Cheers! I'm reluctant to add a new library/dependency that work isn't already using, but I'm glad to have my knowledge of the C# ecosystem grow, much appreciated. It seems the project site for System.Interactive belongs to the RX libraries for C# which I've briefly seen on Java, as well as being closely aligned to Scala design goals.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach alright I see, nevertheless what's the harm of having a select? also, your java code would throw an exception as it's because the `forEach`  will consume the stream `puppies` which you then try to consume again.

Comment: If you want to avoid the `Select`, why not just skip the linq query altogether and just use two nested `foreach` loops?  `foreach (Dog d in dogs) { foreach (Puppy p in puppies) { adopt(d, p); } }`

Comment: @RyanTheLeach - It's a trivial extension method to add if you want to roll your own. That'll keep the extra dependency out of it for you.

Comment: LINQ is for shaping data, in your case a traditional loop should help. It does not make much sense to use linq in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always write this extension method:

```
public static class ForEachEx
{
    public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
    {
        foreach (var item in source) action(item);
    }
}
```

Then you could do either of these options:

```
//option #1
Dogs
    .SelectMany(d => Puppies, (Dog, Puppy) => new { Dog, Puppy })
    .ForEach(pair => Adopt(pair.Dog, pair.Puppy));

//option #2
Dogs.ForEach(d => Puppies.ForEach(p => Adopt(d, p)));
```

Answer (score 1):

If both collections are `List<T>`, List has `ForEach` method:

```
Dogs.ForEach(dog => 
    Puppies.ForEach(puppy => 
        adopt(dog, puppy)));
```

but it will be slower than the simple nested foreach loops:

```
foreach (var dog in Dogs) 
    foreach (var puppy in Puppies) 
        adopt(dog, puppy);
```

---

If `adopt` returns a value, then: (`.Count` is used to enumerate the SelectMany results)

```
Dogs.SelectMany(dog => Puppies, adopt).Count();
```

If `adopt` doesn't return a value, then it gets a bit ugly:

```
Dogs.SelectMany(dog => Puppies, (dog, puppy) => { adopt(dog, puppy); return 0; }).Count();
```